# "ionic build ios" took much time to build in my mac book and also cleared cache ect

Tags: html, node.js, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

> 2018-03-13 17:47:03.715 xcodebuild[3516:90092]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 48ae401249c336192c5c9c042713bb07903d619d was NULL

after that it took much time to build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `cordova platform add ios` command, it is very useful to use xcode to build project. With Xcode you could do debug also.

Comment: With xcode only I was build app.... Bt issue was xcode indexing took more time to load all build files.